# X-AXIS BREAK IN FORESTPLOT PACKAGE

Tags: r, break, line-breaks, r-forestplot, xticks

I have created a graph using Forestplot package. The r-script is following:

```
     forestplot(row_names, OR, low, high,
       txt_gp=fpTxtGp(label=list(gpar(fontfamily="Arial")), 
                      ticks=gpar(cex=1.1),
                      xlab=gpar(cex = 1.2,fontface="bold")),
       is.summary = 
     c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,
                      
      rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,
                      rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,rep(FALSE,3),TRUE,
                      rep(FALSE,49)),
       legend=c("Females", "Males"),
       fn.ci_norm=rep(c("fpDrawNormalCI", "fpDrawCircleCI")),
       xlab="Chronic phlegm",
       xticks= c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24),
       col=fpColors(box="black", lines="black", zero = "black"),
       zero=1, lineheight = "auto", boxsize=0.4, colgap=unit(10,"mm"),
       lwd.ci=1, ci.vertices=TRUE, ci.vertices.height = 0.2, cex=1,clip=c(0.95,1.5),
       new_page = TRUE)
```

I would like to shorten the x-axis by inserting a break at points 8 to 23.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show your effort what you have tried so far.

Comment: I did not find xticksbreak in forestplot package. No idea how to insert break or gap in forestplot package.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I am trying to as well but no luck so far. Thanks.